# loading an image error

Tags: asp.net, css

i have a weird problem i am trying to load an spirte image and get the following error:

"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

i am loading it like that through css:

```
background-image: url('/Img/icons.png');
```

the location is fine cause when i load it through aspx page like that it loads fine:

```
<img src="Img/icons.png" />
```

the location is Img/icons.png
and for css its Css/style.css

its on local host

and i cant figure up whats wrong any help will be appreciate
Thanks.

Comment: Probably it is a server configuration issue, because .asp extension is not configured to load the image. You might need to look at your config file.

Comment: You probably have the path wrong...

Comment: you have an css folder? if so `url('../Img/icons.png');` also! there is an slash `/` in the css url but not in your aspx page src

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your css file is in the same folder as your Img folder, try

```
background-image: url('Img/icons.png');
```

apart from that, you will have to show us your file structure to understand where the error is. 99.99% you are simply referencing the image with the wrong url.

EDIT:

as per the location you've specified, it should be

```
background-image: url('../Img/icons.png');
```

this: `..` means one level above the current location, then look for `/Img/icons.png`

Comment: Saturday night overflow fever!

Comment: so for knowledge  i'am  in css directory and want to get to img directory  /Img/icons.png                                                          the "/" before img doesn't apply to get one level up like         "../" would do?

Comment: no, that "/" at the beginning means "start from the root of my app"

Answer (score 1):

The obvious difference here is the first slash. Looks like your css should be:

```
background-image: url('Img/icons.png');
```

Or alternatively

```
background-image: url('./Img/icons.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:

```
background-image: url('Img/icons.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the relative path to your current page

Try

```
background-image: url('../Img/icons.png');
```

or

```
background-image: url('../../Img/icons.png');
```

or

```
background-image: url('Img/icons.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you also provide the folder structure of the CSS file and the .aspx page ?, that would help us narrow down the issue. From here it seems your css file has navigational issue while accessing the image whereas the aspx doesn't seem to have it because of correct hierarchical path.