# Image Not Displaying In ASP.Net Using VS Code

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html

I have an `asp.net` application and i am trying to setup a `bootstrap 4` `carousel` but the image i have in a folder does not appear and i am stumped as to why not.

The code i have is:

```
<img class="d-block w-100" src="~/Content/Images/PremWhaley.JPG" alt="First slide">
```

I have tried with and without the '~'.

When i console log it i get:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

This is my folder structure

[image]

When i created my project, there was no 'Content' folder so i was wondering if images should be in a specific folder as it has to be for `Angular` projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a 'sort of' solution in another post where they where using `css' to get the`image`.

It was mentioned that the image folder was where the `css` folder is which in my case is in the

> wwwroot

folder.  Thanks to the following post it resolved my issue also

[loading an image error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12992451/loading-an-image-error)